# How to style the roundness of the corner flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a dialog and I need a rounded corners like this:

[image: Expected result]

But when I add BorderRadius to the dialog it's not the same. Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

My code:

```dart
Dialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  elevation: 0,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
  ),
  …
),
```

How can I create rounded corner like first picture or style the roundness?

Comment: Dialog always return full height so try to create a container inside which only hold the widget you wanted to show

Comment: I tried adding container instead of dialog but result is same

Comment: use [ContinuousRectangleBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ContinuousRectangleBorder-class.html) - the docs say: "A rectangular border with smooth continuous transitions between the straight sides and the rounded corners"

Comment: @pskink this is perfect. You saved the day again for me thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think Flutter doens't have smooth corners for rounded so try to use a package name [`smooth_corner`](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_corner)

But there is a lot more on this so try to venture others.

Dialog example although I am using `showGeneralDialog`, the concept of what you want to achieve exists as an example:

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context!,
  barrierColor: const Color(0xFF1A1919).withOpacity(0.3),
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierLabel: '',
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 360),
  transitionBuilder: (c, a, s, ch) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: a.value,
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: a.value,
        child: Dialog(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          // Add a child Column to the dialog, then inside it will be a Container with rounded corners
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: SmoothRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    smoothness: 0.6,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                child: Text(''),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  pageBuilder: (c, r, x0) {
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  },
);
```

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and I see the same roundness. If you see the first pic how corner's roundness drops quickly while in second it takes I think more length or something

Comment: I think you can achieve this by custom painter

Comment: I think try to use a package for this like smooth_corner: ^1.1.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as pskink's suggetion works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

By using:

```
shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(64),
),
```

We can get required type of border style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either use `clip-path` or `custom painter` in Flutter.

If you have the `svg` image of your design then you can go to this [website](https://fluttershapemaker.com/), or if you can draw that shape then you can go this [website](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/)

It will generate all the custom painter code for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ContinuousRectangleBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ContinuousRectangleBorder-class.html) instead of using [`smooth_corner`](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_corner) package. It does not require any packages to be installed:

```dart
Dialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  elevation: 0.0,
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38.0),
  ),
  …
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing this

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            title: const Text("Title"),
            content: const DialogContent(),
            actions: actionWidgets,
          );
        },
      );
```